# Templates render out of order when visiting Ember route directly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

[Here's a JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kozefo/10) demonstrating an issue I'm experiencing. [This is the code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kozefo/10/edit?html,js) for it.

I've run into a situation where if I navigate to a route in Ember.js after the application has been loaded (e.g. using `transitionTo`), everything works. But if I try to navigate to the route directly (by entering the url or refreshing the page once I'm already on the route) it doesn't render correctly.

I'm using `renderTemplate` to place the template into a parent route. But the parent route hasn't been rendered yet when visiting the route directly, so it fails with the following error in the console:

`Cannot read property 'connectOutlet' of undefined`

How can I ensure that the parent route's template is in place to avoid this error?

Comment: You should pull the {{outlet}} out
of the nested template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you render a template into another template programmatically the other template must have already been rendered. You can schedule it to render after it's finished rendering.

```
App.BarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    var self = this;
    Em.run.schedule('afterRender', function(){
      self.render('bar', {into: 'baz'});
    });
  }
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/qilem/1#/bar

Really you're fighting the ember router heavily here.  The application template should have an `{{outlet}}` defined inside of it, but when you use render you've created a nested scope where the outlet no longer exists in the application template.  You can either use `partial` or pull the `{{outlet}}` out of the nested template.

Example Partial: http://jsbin.com/qilem/2#/bar

Example Render: http://jsbin.com/qilem/3#/bar

Comment: Thanks, I ended up pulling the `{{outlet}}` out.